# JSoup Android: Get each results in a separate String

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask, jsoup

OK, What I want to achieve is to write each result `JSoup` fetches me in a separate `String`. Is this somehow possible? I can get the first and last with a function but, yea, then the rest is lost.

right now i have this in my doInBackground:

```
// Connect to the web site
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    // Using Elements to get the Meta data
                    Elements titleElement = document.select("h2[property=schema:name]");
                    // Locate the content attribute
                    date1 = titleElement.toString();

                    Log.e("Date", String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(date1)));
```

With this i get a list of results which is nice, but i'd like to have every result in a separate String.

Thanks in advance, if you need anything more please ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through the documentation carefully again and found this:

```
element.eq(n).text
```

The "n" defines which position to get, the .text strips all the html and makes it a readable text